# Non-exhaustive patterns in function - Maybe type

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, where-clause, option-type

In the following function definition I am getting Non-exhaustive patterns in function tapChar.

What am I missing?

```
reverseTap :: DaPhone -> Char -> [(Digit, Presses)]
reverseTap phone s 
    | isUpper s  = ('*',1) : tapChar (toLower s) phone
    | otherwise = tapChar s phone
    where tapChar s (DaPhone[buttons]) = map (\x -> case (elemIndex s $ phChar x) of
                                         (Just i)  ->  (digit x , i)
                                         Nothing   ->  (' ', (-1))) [buttons]
          phChar (Button _ chars) = chars
          digit  (Button d _)     = d
```

Answer (score 6):

`[buttons]` means "a list with one element, with said one element being bound to `buttons`", but you're using it as if it meant "a list bound to `buttons`". To get that, just use `buttons` instead.